# How to set up a Rake task for seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, seed, rake-task

(This is really a newbie question about Rake & Rails & dependencies in general. Trying to wrap my head around how all this fits together)

Basically, I want a Rake task that acts like seed.rb but is called separately. It adds test data for the development environment, while my seed.rb provides basic data for all environments.

The script, family_seed.rb, uses FactoryGirl to generate some records. It looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require './spec/factories'

Family.delete_all
Member.delete_all
zinsser = Factory.create(:family, :last_name=>'Zinsser', :first_name=>'Carl', :sim_id => '500')
blackburn = Factory.create(:family, :last_name=>'Blackburn', :first_name=>'Greg', :sim_id => '501')
```

It runs fine with `bundle exec "ruby db/family_seeds.rb"`, but my question is how to set it up with Rake. Should the whole thing be placed inside a Rake task? How could I, instead, set up a task that would call the script, while ensuring that the Rails development environment is available when it runs? I'm trying not just to get the job done, but to do it in a "right" way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to create a class or module in lib (this makes it easier to write tests for, and makes the code more reusable):

```
require '../spec/factories'

class FamilySeed

  def self.seed
    raise "Don't run this in production!" if Rails.env.production?

    Family.delete_all
    Member.delete_all
    zinsser = Factory.create(:family, :last_name=>'Zinsser', :first_name=>'Carl', :sim_id => '500')
    blackburn = Factory.create(:family, :last_name=>'Blackburn', :first_name=>'Greg', :sim_id => '501')
  end

end
```

#### How to create the rake task:

```
require 'family_seed'

namespace :seed do
  task :families => :environment do
    FamilySeed.seed
  end
end
```

I'd be careful with allowing things like Family.delete_all and Member.delete_all to be too freely used. You could easily shoot yourself in the foot later on by calling something you didn't mean to on a production db.

#### How to run the rake task:

Run it in your command like with the following:

```
bundle exec rake seed:families
```

Comment: That's an excellent warning! Is there any way to ensure that a task only runs in a given environment? Can the object such as class FamilySeed inspect the environment to see whether it's test or production?

Comment: I've updated the code to raise an exception if the rails env is production.

Comment: @idlefingers thank you for your rake task - how do I call it from the command line?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon you should be able to run it on the command line with something like `bundle exec rake seed:families`

Answer (score 2):

Create a rake task and require :environment

```
task :delete_all => :environement do
  require Rails.root.join('spec/factories')
  Family.delete_all
  Member.delete_all
  zinsser = Factory.create(:family, :last_name=>'Zinsser', :first_name=>'Carl', :sim_id => '500')
  blackburn = Factory.create(:family, :last_name=>'Blackburn', :first_name=>'Greg', :sim_id => '501')
end
```

After you can run this task `rake delete_all`

Comment: This is good for showing how to do it all in one task. The key I was missing is the ... => :environment bit. I like the "delete_all" as the task name -- makes it less likely to run it by accident.