# Creating a multiple choice test on Rails using a hash table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm in a tech summer camp and our teacher is showing us how to use Ruby on Rails. I told my teacher want I wanted to make and he told us to post here because it's important to learn from other developers.

I was looking on the site and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458355/a-quiz-game-on-ruby-on-rails) that is similar to what I want to do for my project. I want my friends to be able to read a few pages of text and then do a short test to make sure they were paying attention.

I want to make a hash table like the question I linked above but I don't know where to put it in my app! I would also like to tie it to users somehow so I can see which of my friends completed the test or not.

So far I have made `user`, `question` and `answer` models and would like to use a hash table like this test my fellow students.

```
# Question:
{ :question_id => 1,
  :text => 'What is Minecraft?',
  :answers => # Answers:
                [{:answer_id => 1, :text => 'A game'},
                 {:answer_id => 2, :text => 'A food'},
                 {:answer_id => 3, :text => 'A store'} ],
  :correct_answer_id => 1 }
```

Can someone tell me where I need to put this in my app and how I can save it to a database?  My teacher said it is okay if people tell us how to do stuff as long as we tell him in our write up.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Normally "thank yous" and such are left out, unlike forums.

Answer (score 1):

If you have related your answers with a `has_many` relationship to your question you can create answers with questions like this:

```
question = Question.create!(text => 'What is Minecraft?')
question.answer.create!(:text => 'A game')
question.answer.create!(:text => 'A food')
...
```

Ids will usually given out by the database, just don't need to define them yourself.

Comment: Hi Axel!  Where would I put this code you just told me?

Comment: A common approach is to create a `seed rake task` for this. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448966/how-to-set-up-a-rake-task-for-seeding